# Problem in basic parameter initialization

Tags: python, parameters, pytorch, initialization

Thanks for your time~  after I run the code, the grad is always zero and the loss is not updating.(I guess it's because the weights is initialized all 0's, but I don't know how to fix it) The code is a basic neural network:

```
class Model(torch.nn.Module):       #class
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()        
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(8,6)        
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(6,4)        
        self.linear3 = torch.nn.Linear(4,1)    
        self.sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.sigmoid(self.linear1(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.linear2(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.linear3(x))
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x
   
model = Model()   #model
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss(size_average = False)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(1000):     # training
    y_pred = model(X_train.float())
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train.float())
    print(epoch, loss.item())
    print([x.grad for x in optimizer.param_groups[0]['params']])
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

And I get the 0s grad:

[image]

Comment: Remove the `softmax` layer, use `Adam` optimizer. Without a [mre] this can hardly be debugged.

Comment: You are right it's about the softmax layer~

Answer (score 0):

I think your forgot to apply the backpropagation. Adding `loss.backward()` just before your print statetements will do the trick (compute the accumulated gradients and store them in `x.grad`). Note that by default your weights are not initialized to 0 here. The default initialization for linear layers are [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L103-L111).